# Android dynamic array of imageviews in relative layout 3 per row

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout

Well,  I would like to seek your help regarding how to show imageviews dynamically 3 per row in relative layout. What I tried so far is I am able to show imageviews one below other because of which I can add maximum 10 images in screen.
            Instead I want to add 3 images per row.
Here is my source code:

```
        int prevTextViewId = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    {
                        final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                        textView.setText(savedListCont[K]);
                        textView.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null, bd,null , null);
                        textView.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                        textView.setMaxLines(1);
                        textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MIDDLE);
                        int curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;
                        textView.setId(curTextViewId);

                        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, prevTextViewId);
                        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

                        prevTextViewId = curTextViewId;

    ll.addView(textView, params);
```

Actually, I can use `gridview` or `gridlayout` for same but these both doesn't suit my project requirement.

```
My layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/home_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks & Regards,
Aditya.J

Comment: It sounds like you want to have nested `LinearLayout` structure where the outer layout is vertically oriented and the inner layout is horizontal with 3 child views (`ImageViews`). Can you please show us your current layout so we can suggest how to adapt it appropriately?

Comment: Sure ishmaelMakitla, but I cannot go with linear layout, as it wont allow me to drag and drop images between them.I should go with relative layout ishmaelMakitla.here is my layout(its just a relative layout)
<RelativeLayout  />

Comment: Hi, to add the layout code, please edit your question - the comment section won't accommodate all of it.

Comment: Hi ishmaelMakitla, As you said, added the xml code.

Comment: Are you sure gridview or gridlayout aren't a possible solution. If not. Can you tell us why?

Comment: Yes, sure ishmaelMakitla, actually in gridview or grid layout I can drag and drop child views but I cannot move imageview or any other childview  to what ever region I have in screen.Gridview or gridlayout will allow us to drag its childviews between one another but we cannot drag and drop it at which ever portion of space we have in screen, relative layout will allow us to do so.

Comment: use RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF in the addRule method to show the text views in the same row.

Comment: Hi Jinesh, thank you for your help on my question and well if I use RIGHT_OF property I will not see images added which crossed mobile screen width.I want to add 3 images per row , I mean from 0 to 2 position Right_of and 3 to 5 position rightoff where 3rd position should be below 2 position.